# XSLT 1.0 variant for distinct-values

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an XSLT in which I create (from the input data) intermediary variables like the following (hard-coded example, but dynamic in nature):

```
<xsl:variable name="variableX">
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C1"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C2"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C3"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C4"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C5"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

I wish to loop over the distinct occurrences of CodePart values. In XSLT 2.0 it's easy:

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values($variableX/ValidCode/@CodePart)">...</xsl:for-each>
```

But how best do this in XSLT 1.0?
Note that I can't use a key, as it's a dynamically determined variable and not part of the input file.

My input file does contain a list of all possible code parts as follows:

```
<root>
    <CodePart><value>CP1</value></CodePart>
    <CodePart><value>CP2</value></CodePart>
    <CodePart><value>CP3</value></CodePart>
</root>
```

So I thought of looping over `//CodePart/value` instead, ensuring uniqueness for starters. But then I need some Xpath expression that includes the condition

"value occurs in the node-set of all $variableX/ValidCode/@CodePart values"

and use something like

```
<xsl:for-each select="//CodePart[..condition..]/value">...</xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a simple form of the Xpath expression I am looking for?
Or is another approach preferable?

Comment: The statement that "`I can't use a key, as it's a dynamically determined variable and not part of the input file`" -- is not true. In fact, the most straightforward and efficient solution to this problem uses keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use directly an XPath - but you should be able to check for only the valid values like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//CodePart/value">
  <xsl:variable name="CodePart" select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="$variableX/ValidCode[@CodePart=$CodePart]">
    . . .
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

or more simply (thanks to the comments):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//CodePart/value">
  <xsl:if test="$variableX/ValidCode[@CodePart=current()]">
    . . .
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

If `$variableX` is not a node set but an XML fragment it needs to be converted to a node set - this is implementation-dependent, using Microsoft processors:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//CodePart/value" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
  <xsl:if test="msxsl:node-set($variableX)/ValidCode[@CodePart=current()]">
    . . .
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is it also possible to include the condition in the `xsl:if` statement as a condition on `//CodePart/value`? Something like `<xsl:for-each select="//CodePart/value[$variableX/ValidCode[@CodePart=current()]]">` (which does not do the trick but may be close)?

Comment: @Maestro13: No, I don't think it is possible: everything you write directly inside the second `[...]` is relative to `$variable/ValidCode` - so you won't be able to access the value you need, that is relative to the outer `//CodePart/value` - hence the need for a variable.

Comment: Well, I don't think you need the variable: `<xsl:if test="$variableX/ValidCode[@CodePart=current()]">` works just as well.

Comment: This will not work in XSLT 1.0, because it is not allowed to use a result tree fragment in a path expression.

Comment: @empo OK that's true - so it will require node-set(). As I am working with libxslt that's no problem - but yes: good remark.

Comment: @Maestro13: you're right, and I stand corrected - you can use `current()` directly

Comment: This has quadratical time complexity (O(m*n)). A more efficient, sublinear solution exists -- using keys.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev can you explain how you arrived at this, and why the key solution has a better performing complexity? Maybe also point out where documentation on complexity calculations can be found?

Comment: @Maestro13: Keys are usually implemented as hash tables -- do have a look at the available resources on the complexity of has-based search (for example in Steve Skiana's "Algorithm Design Manual"). As for how I "arrived at this" ... well may I ask you how one can't know about keys and use them appropriately?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I meant how you arrived at the order m*n

Comment: @Maestro13: If you have a set of `m` values and for each of this `m` values you are searching to find itin a sequence of `N` items  then the time complexity is `O(m*N)`.  Here `m` is the number of `CodePart/value` elements and `N` is the number of `$variableX)/ValidCode` elements.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev shouldn't this be m * average(N)? Remember that my N varies. The figures in practice are: m=23, N varies from 1 to 12, for 40 runs. So what order does that amount to? And I still wonder what the key solution amounts to and whether that's less or not.

Comment: @Maestro13: As far as the big O notation is concerned, `m*N` and `m*average(N)` is exactly the same thing. As for your specific case the values of `m` and `N` are rather small and the difference between the two algorithms might not be too big. However, should you change your data or try the same algorithms say on m and n > 1000, you may find that the key - based algorithm performs around 10000 (ten thousand) times faster.

Answer (score 5):

> Note that I can't use a key, as it's a dynamically determined variable
>   and not part of the input file.

**This simply isn't true.**

**Here is a short, simple and most efficient solution using keys** (btw, not using any conditional instructions or `xsl:for-each` at all :) ):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kCodeByPart" match="ValidCode" use="@CodePart"/>

    <xsl:variable name="variableX">
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C1"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C2"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C3"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C4"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C5"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vCodes" select="ext:node-set($variableX)/*"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "$vCodes[generate-id()
          =
           generate-id(key('kCodeByPart', @CodePart)[1])
           ]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="ValidCode">

  Code Part: <xsl:value-of select="@CodePart"/>
    Codes: <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "key('kCodeByPart', @CodePart)/@Code"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@Code">
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
  Code Part: CP1
    Codes: C1 C3 

  Code Part: CP2
    Codes: C2 C4 C5
```

**Explanation**:

As specified in the **[W3C XSLT 1.0 Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)**:

> ```
> "The key can be used to retrieve a key from a document other than the document containing the context node."
> ```

In the provided solution we don't even use this possibility -- both the context node and the retrieved key are from the same document -- the temporary tree contained in `$vCodes`.

Again there, it is specified that a key can be used for more than one document:

> "A stylesheet declares a set of keys **for each document** using the
>   xsl:key element."

**To put it in simple words**: the indexing is performed on the *current document* (the document that contains the context (current) node).

Comment: Intriguing - learned something new today - I thought keys could only apply to the static input file nodes. I will give this a try in my (obviously far more complex than the example I derivged from it) transformation.

Comment: I had to twist some things around (`ValidCode` nodes also occur in the input file so I had to add a distinguishing level to the variable) but I got it working all right. Performance does not seem to be different though, so could you elaborate on why the key solution would be faster, having a lower complexity level? Or are the complexity levels the same (as far as I can see, the key has to be re-evaluated for each new run of the template where the variable is reconstucted - hence similar to the `xsl:if` construction?).

Comment: @Maestro13: Hash-based search is `O(N/k)` where `k` is the number of different items. If `k` is ~ `N` the time complexity is ~ `O(1)`. A de-duplication algorithm that compares every item to its preceding items is O(N^2). This said, if `N` is a small number, there might be little or no performance difference -- the big O notation makes sence for big-enough values of N. Usually the difference between an O(N) and and an O(N^2) can be measured if the two algorithms are run for `N` and then for `10*N`. The O(N) one will take 10 times more time, while the O(N^2) one takes 100 time more time.

Answer (score 4):

In XPath 1.0, you can emulate the `distinct-values` function by looking for preceding siblings with the same value.

I have simplified your first document to this so it can be easier reproduced (without even using XSLT):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C1"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C2"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C3"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C4"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C5"/>
    <ValidCode CodePart="CP3" Code="C5"/>
</root>
```

Then, the following XPath expression will select only one `CodePart` attribute with each of the values that occur in the document:

```
//ValidCode/@CodePart[not(../preceding-sibling::ValidCode/@CodePart = .)]
```

So, the condition for the `CodePart` attributes to select is that there is no preceding sibling of the `<ValidCode>` element whose `CodePart` attribute has the same value as the currently examined (selected) `CodePart` attribute.

Comment: This won't do - as I said the input document does not contain the dynamic data.

Comment: @Maestro13: Ok, sorry. Maybe I didn't quite understand what you meant by *dynamic data*. This is the same solution as the one shown by Filburt (the other non-selected one), anyway.

Comment: Not exactly - he left the input file and variable intact. And it's not that I don't appreciate his and your effort that I did not select his answer - and yes Filburt did include the necessary node-set() function for creating a node-set from an RTF where MiMo forgot to do so.

Comment: Indeed, I usually minimize the samples to make the problems and the solutions more easily reproducible and more generally applicable. Sorr if this confused matters for you :-/

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve this (without a key) would be to sort and test against `preceding-sibling`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">

    <xsl:variable name="variableX">
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C1"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C2"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP1" Code="C3"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C4"/>
        <ValidCode CodePart="CP2" Code="C5"/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="refvarX" select="msxsl:node-set($variableX)" />

     <xsl:template match="/">
         <root>
             <xsl:for-each select="$refvarX/ValidCode">
                 <xsl:sort select="./@CodePart" data-type="text" />
                 <xsl:if test="not(./@CodePart = preceding-sibling::ValidCode/@CodePart)">
                     <cp>
                         <xsl:value-of select="./@CodePart" />
                     </cp>
                 </xsl:if>
             </xsl:for-each>
         </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good solution - this would be the one I would choose when I would not have the CodePart valid values available in the input - see MiMo's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `node-set()` function, for example with saxon:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/CodePart/value[
   . = saxon:node-set($variableX)/ValidCode/@CodePart]/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
  <!-- template for distinct value -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I am not sure whether this will work; I did try `xsl:for-each` equivalents of this with the msxsl node-set function, and I think it will not work because the node-set is a set of values and the . is just one value. Did you try to run a test?

Comment: Yespica. It's working fine. Please give feedback otherwise I have to remove this answer.